# GoogleMapsAPI - create markers filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm doing a dynamic map using the Google Maps API that uses the markers to mark a list of predefined locations, such as:

```
 self.locations = [{
        name: 'Foxtrot',
        lat: 38.713905,
        lng: -9.1518868,
        type: 'Bar'
     }
```

It also has a Search field that allows you to filter by the name of the locations (`filteredNav`). It should also filter the markers, but...that is the problem.

The recommendation that I have is the following:

> Try writing console.log(self.location_array());.Because location and
>   marker data modal is separate, you'll have to loop through
>   self.location_array() to process and find which one to show, which one
>   to hide by calling setVisible (or setMap) on the marker object.

This is my code:

```
// Create observable array
self.nav = ko.observableArray(self.locations);
// Create empty observable string
self.filter = ko.observable(''); 
// Show nav and filter
self.filteredNav = ko.computed(function() {

    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();

    if (!filter) {
        return self.nav();
    }
    return self.nav().filter(function(i) {
        // Check for proper casing or lowercase
        return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || i.name.indexOf(filter) > -1;
    });

    //THIS IS THE PROBLEM!
    for (var i = 0; i < location_array()[i].length; i++) {
    //??????
        location_array()[i].setVisible(true);
    }//?????

 }
```

note: *observable array* implementation: `vm.location_array()[i]`

[Link to the project](http://inesarmadabras.github.io/Neighborhood-Map-Project/)

So...the question is...how can I do the loop? I've no idea how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you have presented has some 'mysterious' parts. For example, what is `self`, what is `ko`, what is `observableArray` etc. One can only guess what each of these are.

So I will simply describe to you the general logic of how to achieve what you want.

The logic is pretty straightforward.

The same way you filter the places in the sidebar, when you type, you should filter the array of markers to call `setVisible` with `true` or `false`

This means, that when you create the markers, you should store them to a separate array.

Also, when you create a marker, e.g.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
})
```

Add a `name` property, or something similar, to it, like so

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    name: 'Foxtrot`
})
```

so that your created `marker` has a `name` property, which you can use to filter your array of markers.

Thus, in order to filter your markers array, you should simply iterate over the array and check the `.name` property of each `marker` object, and if the name does not match the search input, simply `setVisible(false)` on the marker, otherwise do `setVisible(true)`

Hope this helps.